# How to sync from azure cloud to a local server

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, entra-id

I'm new to this company which only has an azure active directory in the cloud.

- I'm tasked with getting azure active directories from the cloud to sync to my local server.
- All the guides I've read thus far go from local to cloud sync. I need the **cloud to local sync**.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to sync what exactly? Users? If so, you can't sync users from Azure AD to on premises AD.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need to do. Is there another solution to this problem? Third party?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve exactly?

Comment: To use the local AD with the firewall, VPN along with 2FA in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot sync user/Password from azure active directory to on-premises, you only can sync from on-premises to azure active directory with Azure AD Connect.

You can export the list of users from your azure AD:

1. Sign in to your Azure AD organization https://aad.portal.azure.com/.
2. Navigate to Azure Active Directory > Users.
3. In Azure AD, select Users > Download users. By default, all user profiles are exported.
4. On the Download users page, select Start to receive a CSV file listing user profile properties. If there are errors, you can download and view the results file on the Bulk operation results page. The file contains the reason for each error.

The following user attributes are included:

- userPrincipalName
- displayName
- surname
- mail
- givenName
- objectId
- userType
- jobTitle
- department
- accountEnabled
- usageLocation
- streetAddress
- state
- country
- physicalDeliveryOfficeName
- city
- postalCode
- telephoneNumber
- mobile
- authenticationAlternativePhoneNumber
- authenticationEmail
- alternateEmailAddress
- ageGroup
- consentProvidedForMinor
- legalAgeGroupClassification

As you can see you can't export the password by any means.

Hopes this helps!